# Understanding the use of ConfigureServices in ASP.NET core while keeping seperation of Concerns

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, refactoring, modularity

I would like to understand more about the bellow and I seek somebody experienced to explain and help me to grasp the concepts.

While studying this article: https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-node-d3js/
it begins by adding Node to the ConfigurationServices method in asp.net core:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddNodeServices();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

by default (on a new .net core project) the method looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

and if I implement the above I suppose that it will look like this :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddNodeServices();
            services.AddMvc();#

        }
```

1st part of the question:
Any objections until now?
Any better suggestions?
How would one explain/pronounce this function in a sentence?

If not, I get to my main (2nd part of the) question:
How would that function be refactored to have its concerns separated?

Thank you, community, in advance!

Comment: Perhaps I am missing your point, but the concern of the `ConfigureServices` method is to "configure some services" - does it really matter if it's one or many services?

Comment: Thinking about it another way - it's not possible to have working software without some degree of *administrative* code, which this is an example of. The reason it looks like this is that separation of concerns has already been applied to 'Adding Razor Pages', 'Adding MVC' etc.

Comment: Thank you, both were helpful answers.